# Launch new window, set its size and parameters, from image map

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I have an image with 22 defined map zones. The map looks like this:

```
map name="22_zones"
area shape="circle" coords="251,528,29" href="registration.php?r=22"
area shape="circle" coords="308,451,28" href="registration.php?r=21"
.
.
.
.
/map
```

I would like the map-driven hyperlink to spawn a new window, and set it size/scroll/size etc. In other instances -- not an image map -- I would use something like:

```
a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('../registration.php?r=22', 'none',menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=470,height=550');"
```

Can this approach be adapted to an image map?

Answer (score 1):

By the way, if you want to avoid inline JS, you can use:

```
var areas = document.querySelectorAll('map[name="name"] area');
for (var i = 0, j = areas.length; i < j; i++) {
    areas[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.open(e.target.href, 'none','menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=470,height=550');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. It turns out HTML and Javascript require correct spelling. The fix:

```
<area shape="circle"
```

coords="251,528,29" target="_blank" 
href="#" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://www.townofsilvercity.org/pickitupsc/registration.php?r=14', 'none', 'menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,width=470,height=550');">